# WooCommerce: Dynamic Custom Checkout Fields in admin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, custom-fields

I am having issues adding custom checkout fields to the order admin (and maybe emails, i'm not there yet). Coding issues aside, I mostly followed https://www.kathyisawesome.com/woocommerce-customize-checkout-fields/ - here's my code so far:

http://pastebin.com/y8LDcDxS

I have it adding 'x' amount of $fields['extra_fields'] based on product quantity, assuming one product in the cart. I'm struggling with kia_display_order_data_in_admin() - I keep getting bit by get_country() whatever I do. I've got the non-dynamic variation (based on having two products in the cart) in the pastebin - everything else i've tried to make this part dynamic doesn't work.

I see some options to get these dynamic fields loaded in admin but I just cant get there:

1. Grab product quantity again and append $i to the end of the standard field names
2. Somehow get an array of all fields so I can extract $fields['extra_fields']
3. Get the extra_fields post meta by order_id
4. Something else?

**EDIT:** After Kia's help, I have revised the code a little and it will now dynamically add custom checkout fields. This works all the way up to the admin order screen, but won't work when trying to update order details in admin `kia_save_extra_details()`

**EDIT 2:** Please see the accepted answer below as this works for my question

Comment: Thanks for checking out my website. :) I've answered how to set up the display in the checkout. Hopefully, you can take it from there.

Comment: did you get a chance to try this?

Comment: I did try your code below but couldn't suss it out/get it to work. THank you for the heads up though in building the initial array of fields - got rid of some code repetition. New [pastebin.com/PnvGCGRG](http://pastebin.com/PnvGCGRG). It works all the way up to the admin order screen when trying to update after editing the details in admin. Have not tried emails yet, but I am thinking as these will be product related (much like how these checkout fields should be), I might try one of the [SkyVerge tutorials](https://www.skyverge.com/blog/how-to-add-a-custom-woocommerce-email/)

Comment: You don't need to use pastebin, you can paste the code into your question.

Comment: See @helgatheviking accepted answer below for solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you sure Product Add-Ons might not be more suited to this? If not, I think what you need is a custom input type. This should get you started.

```
/* Add a new checkout field 
 * 
 * These is our base field group, later on, depending on product quanitiy, $key = 'passenger_title_1' for example
 * 
 */

function supreme_filter_checkout_fields($fields){
    $fields['extra_fields'] = array(
    'passenger_details' => array(
        'type' => 'passenger_details',
        'required'      => false,
        'label' => __( 'Passenger Details' )
        ),
    );

    return $fields;

}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'supreme_filter_checkout_fields' );
```

What the heck is a "passenger_details" input? Well, we're going to define that because `woocommerce_form_field()` has a catch all in case the type doesn't match any of WooCommerce's defaults. See [`'woocommerce_form_field_' . $args['type']`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/d7aea130b0e918e819d15275933f581e3811d8a2/includes/wc-template-functions.php#L1961)

Here is where we're going to list the group of fields that you want for each passenger.

```
function supreme_filter_checkout_field_group( $field, $key, $args, $value ){
    $op_cart_count = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count();

    $html = '';

    for ( $i = 1; $i <= $op_cart_count; $i++) {

        $html .= woocommerce_form_field( "passenger_details[$i][title]", array( 
            "type" => "select",
            "return" => true,
            "value" => "",
            "options" => array( "mr" => __( "Mr" ), "mrs" => __( "Mrs" ), "miss" => __( "Miss" ) ),
            "required"      => false,
            "label" => __( "Title" )
            )
        );
        $html .= woocommerce_form_field( "passenger_details[$i][first_name]", array(
            "type" => "text",
            "return" => true,
            "value" => "",
            "required"      => false,
            "label" => __( "First Name" )
            )
        );
        $html .= woocommerce_form_field( "passenger_details[$i][middle_name]", array(
            "type" => "text",
            "return" => true,
            "value" => "",
            "required"      => false,
            "label" => __( "Middle Name" )
            )
        );
        $html .= woocommerce_form_field( "passenger_details[$i][last_name]", array(
            "type" => "text",
            "return" => true,
            "value" => "",
            "required"      => false,
            "label" => __( "Last Name" )
            )
        );
        $html .= woocommerce_form_field( "passenger_details[$i][date_of_birth]", array(
            "type"          => "text",
            "return" => true,
            "value" => "",
            "class"         => array("date-of-birth form-row-wide"),
            "required"      => false,
            "label"         => __("Date of Birth"),
            "placeholder"       => __("Select Date"),
            "options"     =>   array("" => __("Date of Birth", "woocommerce" ))
            )
        );
        $html .= woocommerce_form_field( "passenger_details[$i][dietary_required]", array(
            "type" => "select",
            "return" => true,
            "value" => "",
            "class"         => array("dietary-required form-row-wide"),
            "options" => array( "" => __( "Please Select" ), "y" => __( "Yes" ), "n" => __( "No" ) ),
            "required"      => false,
            "label" => __( "Dietary Requirements?" )
            )
        );
        $html .= woocommerce_form_field( "passenger_details[$i][dietary_preference]", array(
            "type" => "select",
            "return" => true,
            "value" => "",
            "class"         => array("dietary-requirements form-row-wide"),
            "options" => array( "v" => __( "Vegetarian" ), "GF" => __( "Gluten Free" ) ),
            "required"      => false,
            "label" => __( "Meal Preferences" )
            )
        );

    }
    return $html;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field_passenger_details', 'supreme_filter_checkout_field_group', 10, 4 );



// display the extra field on the checkout form
function supreme_extra_checkout_fields(){ 

    $checkout = WC()->checkout();

    foreach ( $checkout->checkout_fields['extra_fields'] as $key => $field ) :

        woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field, $checkout->get_value( $key ) );

    endforeach;


}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_after_customer_details' ,'supreme_extra_checkout_fields' );
```

**EDIT** Handle sanitization and saving of data. Note that I changed the `supreme_filter_checkout_field_group` function above and removed the ID parameter.

~~Using the `id` argument we can dynamically set the input name. The resulting markup should be something like:~~

```
<input type="text" class="input-text " name="last_name" id="passenger_details[2]last_name" placeholder="" value="">
```

This was wrong. the `name` parameter needs to be an array! And the name is pulled from the first parameter of `woocommerce_form_field()`. The ID is irrelevant to our needs, though does need to be unique to maintain proper markup. This is the result we need and should now be getting with the above modification:

```
<input type="text" class="input-text " name="passenger_details[2][last_name]" id="passenger_details[2][last_name]" placeholder="" value="">
```

Now on submit the `$_POST['passenger_data']` should be an array (passenger) of arrays (passenger details). And after my edit, it is!

Now, to process this data and sanitize the individual fields in the passenger data we create a function for sanitizing our custom field type:

```
/**
 * Sanitize our custom field
 * 
 */
function supreme_custom_process_checkout_field_passenger_details( $posted ){

    $clean = array();

    foreach( $posted as $passenger ){
        $details = supreme_custom_checkout_clean_passenger_details( $passenger );

        if( ! empty( $details ) ){
            $clean[] = $details;
        }
    }

    return $clean;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_process_checkout_passenger_details_field', 'supreme_custom_process_checkout_field_passenger_details' );


function supreme_custom_checkout_clean_passenger_details( $passenger = array() ){
    $details = array();
    if( isset( $passenger["title"] ) ){
        $details['title'] = sanitize_text_field( $passenger["title"] );
    }
    if( isset( $passenger["first_name"] ) ){
        $details['first_name'] = sanitize_text_field( $passenger["first_name"] );
    }
    if( isset( $passenger["middle_name"] ) ){
        $details['middle_name'] = sanitize_text_field( $passenger["middle_name"] );
    }
    if( isset( $passenger["last_name"] ) ){
        $details['last_name'] = sanitize_text_field( $passenger["last_name"] );
    }
    if( isset( $passenger["date_of_birth"] ) ){
        $details['date_of_birth'] = $date = preg_replace("([^0-9/])", "", $passenger["date_of_birth"] );
    }
    if( isset( $passenger["dietary_required"] ) ){
        $details['dietary_required'] = $passenger["dietary_required"] == "y" ? "y": "n";
    }
    if( isset( $passenger["dietary_preference"] ) && isset( $passenger["dietary_required"] ) && $passenger["dietary_required"] == "y" ){
        $details['dietary_preference'] = $passenger["dietary_preference"] == "GF" ? "GF": "v";
    }
    return $details;
}
```

Now that it is sanitized, updating is just a matter of saving the post meta:

```
/**
 * update_post_meta
 * 
 */
function supreme_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id, $posted ){

    if( ! empty( $posted["passenger_details"] ) ){
        update_post_meta( $order_id, "_passenger_details", $posted["passenger_details"] );
    } else {
        delete_post_meta( $order_id, "_passenger_details" );
    }

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'supreme_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta', 10, 2 );
```

Now, we definitely have all the fields saved in the `_passenger_details` post meta key and we can loop through that array any time we need to display it. For example, here it is on the admin order page:

```
// display the extra data in the order admin panel
function kia_display_order_data_in_admin( $order ){  

    $passenger_details = get_post_meta( $order->id, "_passenger_details", true ); 

    if( ! empty( $passenger_details ) ) { 

        $passenger_defaults = array(
                "title" => "",
                "first_name" => "",
                "middle_name" => "",
                "last_name" => "",
                "date_of_birth" => "",
                "dietary_required" => "",
                "dietary_preference" => ""
            );

    ?>
    <div class="passenger_data">
        <h4><?php _e( "Passenger Details", "your-slug" ); ?></h4>
        <?php 
            $i = 1;

            foreach( $passenger_details as $passenger ){

                $passenger = wp_parse_args( $passenger, $passenger_defaults );

                echo "<p><strong>" . sprintf( __( "Passenger #%s", "your-slug" ), $i  ) . "</strong>" . "<br/>";
                echo __( "Title", "your-slug" ) . ' : ' . $passenger["title"] . "<br/>";
                echo __( "First Name", "your-slug" ) . ' : ' . $passenger["first_name"] . "<br/>";
                echo __( "Middle Name", "your-slug" ) . ' : ' . $passenger["middle_name"] . "<br/>";
                echo __( "Last Name", "your-slug" ) . ' : ' . $passenger["last_name"] . "<br/>";
                echo __( "Date of Birth", "your-slug" ) . ' : ' . $passenger["date_of_birth"] . "<br/>";
                echo __( "Dietary Required", "your-slug" ) . ' : ' . $passenger["dietary_required"] . "<br/>";
                echo __( "Dietary Preference", "your-slug" ) . ' : ' . $passenger["dietary_preference"] . "<br/>";

                echo "</p>";

                $i++;

            }

         ?>
    </div>
<?php }
}
add_action( "woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details", "kia_display_order_data_in_admin" );
```

That still leaves the thankyou page and emails now, but the data is there.

Comment: @tringwebdesign what results to you get from this? (it didn't work is always vague) what part didn't work? I can try to take a second look when I have time.

Comment: It wouldn't dynamically add additional checkout fields. TBH I know it's only been 6 days since your kind input, but I can't remember the outcome of using the code above, it obviously didn't work as a pure copy & paste snippet hence my revised edit to the original question. I can go back and re-test if you wish?

Comment: Looking at this again, while the inputs were displaying they did not have the desired "name" property. Please check out the modified answer. I've tested it and it does save the data.

Comment: Thank you @helgatheviking it does indeed work, some margarita love sent your way! All to do now is to get admin order edit working. I spoke to my client since and he is going to use Zapier to manage order emails to suppliers etc.